# Change arrow color photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion

What should I do to change this arrow color for example to #22A5D8

I am using photoshop cs5

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a layer style and apply a colour overlay:

[image]

Comment: After this I lost white background

Comment: @zolter create it from scratch using two rectangles which you rotate slightly to form an arrow. Put them in a group and add a dropshadow layer effect and the Color overlay (as described in the answer) to that group. Use the image you have as reference and simply hide or delete it when you're done.

Comment: @zolter Just create a new layer beneath the arrow that is filled white.

Comment: @Spedwards That won't accomplish anything.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see the drop shadow. @AndroidHustle gives the correct answer here

Answer (score 0):

The white background of the arrow should be transparent first. If you don't have the copy of the arrow with transparent background do this:

1. Go to Select -> Color Range.
2. Hold Control button and Pick a white color part in the image.
3. Click Ok.
4. Press Delete in your keyboard when the white part of the image is selected.
5. do what @KJP said.

Note: This procedure might make the arrow's outer pixels jagged

Answer (score 0):

**BEST METHOD**

choose `Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation...`

or `ctrl+u` (PC)

or `command+u` (Mac)

Drag the `Hue` marker to change the color to your liking then choose `ok`

[image]

**EDIT** **(this method works also but doesn't give a nice result)**

Do as @KJP mentioned by adding a color overlay but change the blend mode to "**Hue**" to keep the white background **and not affect the shadow**:

[image]

Comment: Won't that also color the small dropshadow? Or does Color blend mode not affect gray scale (since it doesn't affect white)? Don't have PS in front of me to check..

Comment: @AndroidHustle Ah, it may do. I never noticed the shadow.

Comment: @AndroidHustle edited my answer.